# <select> values not passed when css class is added

Tags: php, html, css

i have a form which im using php and html. There is a strange problem.

I have a several drop down menus

```
 <select id="probab" name="probab" class="selector regular">

                         <option value="0%">0%</option>
                        <option value="10%">10%</option>
                        <option value="20%">20%</option>
                        <option value="30%">30%</option>
                        <option value="40%">40%</option>
                        <option value="50%">50%</option>
                        <option value="60%">60%</option>
                        <option value="70%">70%</option>
                        <option value="80%">80%</option>
                        <option value="90%">90%</option>
                        <option value="100%">100%</option>
                    </select>
```

when i submit the form the values in "probab" doesnt pass. But when i remove

class="selector regular"

my css

```
.box .selector {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

i dont see any style for "regular" in the css.

the values are passed from the form.

can anyone tellme what the problem is?

Comment: Is there any javascript involved?

Comment: @DiegoAgulló jquery.uniform.min.js is being used to the form i guess.. although there are many other js used for this template.

Comment: I'm afraid some javascript must me interfering, as the code you have posted is just fine.

Comment: try removing id from the list if not required

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine..the problem lies somewhere else..

probably you have another select list with same name..

Comment: class="selector regular" when i remove that the code works perfectly but i lose my styles :(. There is only one drop down with that name.

Comment: Try removing just the 'selector' class and see if it works. Then if not try removing just the 'regular' class and see if it works. Process of emilination.